# Porting ESP32 CameraWebServer example to https

Tags: https, esp32

I am trying to run the [Arduino-ESP32 CameraWebServer](https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/tree/master/libraries/ESP32/examples/Camera/CameraWebServer) example on https instead of http. I started by including esp_https_server.h instead of esp_http_server.h and changing the startCameraServer() function as follows:

```cpp
void startCameraServer(){
#ifndef _ESP_HTTPS_SERVER_H_
  httpd_config_t config = HTTPD_DEFAULT_CONFIG();
#else
  httpd_ssl_config config = HTTPD_SSL_CONFIG_DEFAULT();
  config.cacert_len = cert->getCertLength();
  config.cacert_pem = cert->getCertData();
  config.prvtkey_len = cert->getPKLength();
  config.prvtkey_pem = cert->getPKData();
#endif
  httpd_uri_t index_uri = { .uri = "/", .method = HTTP_GET, .handler = index_handler, .user_ctx = NULL };
  httpd_uri_t status_uri = { .uri = "/status", .method = HTTP_GET, .handler = status_handler, .user_ctx = NULL };
  httpd_uri_t cmd_uri = { .uri = "/control", .method = HTTP_GET, .handler = cmd_handler, .user_ctx = NULL };
  httpd_uri_t capture_uri = { .uri = "/capture", .method = HTTP_GET, .handler = capture_handler, .user_ctx = NULL };
  httpd_uri_t stream_uri = { .uri = "/stream", .method = HTTP_GET, .handler = stream_handler, .user_ctx = NULL };

  ra_filter_init(&ra_filter, 20);
    
  mtmn_config.type = FAST;
  mtmn_config.min_face = 80;
  mtmn_config.pyramid = 0.707;
  mtmn_config.pyramid_times = 4;
  mtmn_config.p_threshold.score = 0.6;
  mtmn_config.p_threshold.nms = 0.7;
  mtmn_config.p_threshold.candidate_number = 20;
  mtmn_config.r_threshold.score = 0.7;
  mtmn_config.r_threshold.nms = 0.7;
  mtmn_config.r_threshold.candidate_number = 10;
  mtmn_config.o_threshold.score = 0.7;
  mtmn_config.o_threshold.nms = 0.7;
  mtmn_config.o_threshold.candidate_number = 1;
   
  face_id_init(&id_list, FACE_ID_SAVE_NUMBER, ENROLL_CONFIRM_TIMES);
    
#ifndef _ESP_HTTPS_SERVER_H_
  Serial.printf("Starting web server on port: '%d'\n", config.server_port);
  if (httpd_start(&camera_httpd, &config) == ESP_OK) {
#else
  Serial.printf("Starting web server on port: '%d'\n", config.port_secure);
  if (httpd_ssl_start(&camera_httpd, &config) == ESP_OK) {
#endif
    httpd_register_uri_handler(camera_httpd, &index_uri);
    httpd_register_uri_handler(camera_httpd, &cmd_uri);
    httpd_register_uri_handler(camera_httpd, &status_uri);
    httpd_register_uri_handler(camera_httpd, &capture_uri);
  }

#ifndef _ESP_HTTPS_SERVER_H_
  config.server_port += 1;
  config.ctrl_port += 1;
  Serial.printf("Starting stream server on port: '%d'\n", config.server_port);
  if (httpd_start(&stream_httpd, &config) == ESP_OK) {
#else
  config.port_secure += 1;
  config.httpd.ctrl_port += 1;
  Serial.printf("Starting stream server on port: '%d'\n", config.port_secure);
  if (httpd_ssl_start(&stream_httpd, &config) == ESP_OK) {
#endif
    httpd_register_uri_handler(stream_httpd, &stream_uri);
  }
}
```

If I include esp_http_server.h the original code will compile and everything runs fine. If I include esp_https_server.h the changes will compile and the webserver nicely comes up at port 443. The menu shows and I can get a still from the camera. The only thing that doesn't work is what it's all about: the live stream. The video window shows but only with a broken image icon. I see no messages in the terminal window in PlatformIO or anything in the browser's console. The stream_handler function, defined in stream_uri, is called when using http but not when using https.

My knowledge about webserver software is very minimalistic, I have no idea where to look further.

Does anybody know if I could get this working, any ideas?

Comment: Look for messages in the web browser's console. I'm betting you didn't change the video stream's port number in the HTML.

Comment: @omkey No messages there (by "in the webbrowser" I meant "in the webbrowser's console". I have updated the text.)

Comment: @romkey But you're absolutely right: the broken stream's link has the original port number. The corresponding HTML is burried somewhere deep in the ESP32 code, haven't found it yet ...

Comment: I'm not sure where the HTML is buried and I don't know if there's a simple option for changing the stream's port number. You could do something awful and run SSL on port 80... as long as you use `https://camera:80/` it should work, though it's a terrible thing to do :)

Comment: Found the HTML! It's ... interesting :) [This line references it](https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/blob/371f382db7dd36c470bb2669b222adf0a497600d/libraries/ESP32/examples/Camera/CameraWebServer/app_httpd.cpp#L587) - it's stored, gzipped, as a byte array [here](https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/blob/371f382db7dd36c470bb2669b222adf0a497600d/libraries/ESP32/examples/Camera/CameraWebServer/camera_index.h#L280). To update it you'd need to extract it, ungzip it, modify it, gzip it, and then store the binary file as bytes in this array.

Comment: Yeah, I saw those bytes but didn't realize yet it was the zipped HTML. Thx for your help! In the meantime I found an [expanded version of the example](https://github.com/easytarget/esp32-cam-webserver) that uses readable HTML and helps understanding the code.

I also tried to run the SSL stream  on port 81 and for a very short moment I had a video stream. But for some reason I can't reproduce that and there are frequent out of memory error messages. Perhaps tweeking of the ESP32 partitioning table can solve that, I'll keep on experimenting :)